# How to use send requests with Celebrate Joi validation with Express Router?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, joi

[image]I am trying to test the route below with with postman, but I am getting the below defined error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. In Postman I am putting the data in raw. I need some help with this one. Thx ahead!

```
app.use('/auth', route);

  route.post(
    '/signup',
    celebrate({
      body: Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().required(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const logger = Container.get('logger') as winston.Logger;
      logger.debug('Calling Sign-Up endpoint with body: %o', req.body )
      try {
        const authServiceInstance = Container.get(AuthService);
        console.log(authServiceInstance)
        const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.SignUp(req.body as IUserInputDTO);
        console.log(user, token)
        return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
      } catch (e) {
        logger.error('error: %o', e);
        return next(e);
      }
    },
  );
```

I am getting this error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "child \"name\" fails because [\"name\" is required]"
    }
}
```

whilst trying to use this JSON as a test input in JSON

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "password": "123abc"
}
```

the userInputDTO is as follows

```
export interface IUserInputDTO {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

this is the post on postman

> http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup

Comment: can you show the full HTTP request going up? Are you using the correct `Content-Type` when POSTing?

Comment: I have added a snipped of postman above my description of the problem

Comment: hmm looks fine, I presume your Node app is configured to handle JSON requests? Can you show your express setup?

Comment: @James I am using app.use(bodyParser.json()); in an express.ts file

Comment: presumably that's all setup *before* your routes? Could you share the request headers? Helps rule out the content-type, also there is an exclamation mark next to the JSON option in Postman, is that indicating an issue worth looking at?

Comment: @James thanks for giving me that hint! It resolved the issue for the placeholder error of the userInputDTO.

Comment: as suspected, sounds like the issue was indeed the format of the request coming up, it most likely wasn't valid JSON thus not being parsed correctly at the server.